# Reddit API get comments as they come

Tags: haskell, reddit

I have a function that takes in a Reddit comment and spits out a reply. I want this function to map over every new comment posted on Reddit.

How should I get the comments from reddit? It seems a bit wasteful to just pull in the 100 most recent comments very often so none are missed. A way to get all comments newer than a specific comment be very good.

Ideally the comments would just be a lazy list so I just could do

```
f :: Comment -> IO ()

getComments :: IO [Comment]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  comments <- getComments
  traverse_ f comments
```

Or I could write an interact function:

```
f :: Comment -> Comment

interact :: (Comment -> Comment) -> IO ()

main :: IO ()
main = interact f
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Reddit API, but I'm guessing you're going to need to use the pagination options in the `Options` record. That said, what I've seen of the documentation (of both the Haskell package and the underlying API) is fairly lousy, so you may have to do some experimenting. You may also find that the Haskell package doesn't give you enough access to the underlying API; I'm not sure.

Comment: @dfeuer: That's it, thank you!

Comment: @LeifMetcalf I suggest you to post your solution as a self-answer.

Comment: @duplode Is what I wrote ok?

Comment: @LeifMetcalf It is fine. For the icing on the cake, consider adding your comment-grabbing function to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [comments endpoint](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_comments_%7Barticle%7D) has a query parameter `before`. A request with this query parameter set to the `name` of any comment will return *only* the comments which are newer than that comment.

Note that the `name` of a comment is not its `link_id`, which is what I was stuck on.

For example, a request to [www.reddit.com/r/foobar/comments.json?sort=new&before=t1_e9eud8s](https://reddit.com/r/foobar/comments.json?sort=new&before=t1_e9eud8s) will return a listing of the comments that were posted *after* the comment with `name: t1_e9eud8s`